# VBA Excel: How can I use VLookup and IF in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How can I do this in VBA?

```
IF(VLOOKUP(E3;Tabel5;2;0)>=F26;VLOOKUP(E3;Tabel5;4;0)*F26;)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: please describe what you are trying to do (instead of just giving the alternative excel function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this code:
First way (you can use user defined function):

```
Function getSomeData(E3 As Range, Table5 As Range, F26 As Range)      
   getSomeData = ""

   If WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E3, Table5, 2, 0) >= F26 Then
      getSomeData= WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E3, Table5, 4, 0) * F26
   End If
End Function
```

Than you can call it in any cell just typing `=getSomeData(E3;Tabel5;F26)` in it. Advantages of this approach is that when you change data in related cells (`E3`, `F26` or `Table5`), function will recalculate the value in cell.

Second way:

```
Sub getSomeDataSub()    
   Dim E3 As Range, F26 As Range, Table5 As Range

   Range("F27") = ""
   Set E3 = Range("E3")
   Set Table5 = Range("Table5")
   Set F26 = Range("F26")
   If WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E3, Table5, 2, 0) >= F26 Then
      Range("F27")= WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E3, Table5, 4, 0) * F26
   End If
End Sub
```

you can call this macros from the ribbon and it will put some data in `F27` cell. In this approach you should call this macro each time you change values in related cells to recalculate it in `F27`.

Comment: ,How Can I make that VBA code run in cell F27 ? Thank you for the quick respons :)

Comment: The first one works great - but it doesn’t update automatically, I have to manually update the cell F27. Is' it possible that cell F27 automatically works as soon as the cell F26 changes? :)

Comment: Thanks for the help it works perfectly. Just a question is it possible to insert two additional functions in the code:
This in cell F26: = SUM (Tabel4 [Total])
and this in cell F28: = F27 + F26

Thank you again :)

Comment: Sorry I did not get accepted your answer immediately - I'm new here.
How can I add the two functions in the code? Thank you :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, than try this functions:  `Function addValues(F27 As Range, F26 As Range)
    addValues = F27 + F26
End Function` for `F26` cell and 
`Function TableSum(Table4 As Range)
    TableSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Table4)
End Function` for `F28` cell

Comment: You have understood me correctly but how do I merge it into the first code? :)

Comment: You should use 3 separate user difined functions: `getSomeData` , `addValues`, `TableSum`. If you want it to be in one functions - it's better to use second approach by adding two lines: in the very beggining of function : `Range("F26")=WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("Table4"))` and in the end of function : `Range("F28")=Range("F27")+Range("F26")`